# Objective C - Receive TCP request with no encoding

Tags: objective-c, encoding, tcp

I am trying to create an app that receive a binary file from a server, and stores it as a pdf on the IOS device. I am sending the binary files in an unencoded form to the app. However, I cannot find out how to not use encoding on the app itself.

```
len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                                NSString *pdfFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:0];
```

I have tried changing the encoding to null. However, in the console it prints that it is automatically giving it encoding.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your question and code are confused.  Are you sending the name or the PDF itself?

Comment: I am sending the binary file of the PDF

Comment: Then why are you trying to store it in an `NSString`?  A PDF is not a string.

Comment: I was going to write it to a file afterwards. If there is an easier way to do it, please tell me as I'm pretty new to Objective-C

Comment: Thanks, so if I use NSData, will it not automatically try to un-encode the data?

Comment: You mean automatically try to *en*code?  Strings have to be encoded, but `NSData` is just a collection of bytes.